# syn::Field.attrs doesn't contain inert attributes

Tags: rust

Given the following struct definition:

```
#[derive(Builder)]
pub struct Command {
    executable: String,
    #[builder(each = "arg")]
    args: Vec<String>,
    #[builder(each = "env")]
    env: Vec<String>,
    current_dir: Option<String>,
}
```

(where the `#[builder(...)]` attributes are inert attributes defined by my `Builder` derive macro implementation),
the `Builder` macro cannot "see" the `#[builder(...)]` field attributes. The following code

```
    let name = &f.ident;
    let attrs = &f.attrs;
    println!("Attributes: {:?}: {}", name, attrs.len());
```

(where `f` is a `syn::Field`) gives

```
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "executable", span: #0 bytes(2830..2840) }): 0
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "args", span: #0 bytes(2854..2858) }): 0
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "env", span: #0 bytes(2877..2880) }): 0
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "current_dir", span: #0 bytes(2899..2910) }): 0
```

(Full code: https://github.com/pdkovacs/forked-proc-macro-workshop/blob/a471007968f974ea3c1c684cc47a77fbd20b91dc/builder/src/lib.rs)

Can anybody help me find out what I am missing here, please?

Comment: For posterity: https://github.com/pdkovacs/forked-proc-macro-workshop/blob/a471007968f974ea3c1c684cc47a77fbd20b91dc/builder/src/lib.rs is now available as https://github.com/pdkovacs/forked-proc-macro-workshop/blob/trybuild-gotcha/builder/src/lib.rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might just be interpreting the terminal output incorrectly since when I cloned your fork and removed the test code that failed to compile this is the output I got for the test with the attributes:

```rs
test tests/07-repeated-field.rs ... ok

WARNINGS:
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
warning: unused import: `builder_trait:: Builder`
  --> tests/07-repeated-field.rs:32:5
   |
32 | use builder_trait:: Builder;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈

STDOUT:
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "executable", span: #0 bytes(1471..1481) }): 0
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "args", span: #0 bytes(1524..1528) }): 1
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "env", span: #0 bytes(1576..1579) }): 1
Attributes: Some(Ident { ident: "current_dir", span: #0 bytes(1598..1609) }): 0
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈

STDERR:
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
warning: unused import: `builder_trait:: Builder`
  --> /home/cassy/projects/forked-proc-macro-workshop/builder/tests/07-repeated-field.rs:32:5
   |
32 | use builder_trait:: Builder;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
```

To be clear I completely commented out the body of `main` in `07-repeated-field.rs` since it was failing to compile, and doing so allowed me to see this output.

I haven't used `trybuild` before but it seems like if a test fails to build then it doesn't give you the output from the proc macro invocation. Moreover it displays the `STDOUT`/`STDERR` of the test compilation process after it displays the test name, which likely was the source of the confusion.